# Python - phase shift of two sine waves with different frequency

Tags: python, signal-processing

Is there a possibility to get the phase shift between two sine signals with different frequencies. In my example the raw data would have a sine wave at ~50 kHz and a second sine wave at ~150 kHz.

Actual i found only possibilities of phase calculation with same frequencies.

Sample Rate: 12500000 samples/s

Frequency 1: 48828.125 Hz

Frequency 2: 3*48828.125 Hz

[results1.txt](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492423969117.txt)

[results2.txt](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1492424024509.txt)

[image: Signals]

Comment: Since one frequency is a multiple of other 150, 50 you can get phase difference between them at points where they intersect. ie after 3 cycles of the 150 sine wave. Would that be okay?

Comment: That would be ok.

Comment: Since you have the time series data, you can start with finding the point where the phase of 50 wave becomes 0 (look for the point where it goes from negative to positive and interpolate). Look for the value of the 150 wave at this point. Appying sin inverse at that point will give you the phase at that point. This is your difference.

Comment: Yes it is limited by sampling frequency. There is another option. If you know that the first entry is for t = 0, you can calculate the phase for both the waves at the first entry and substract them. Thus you won't need any interpolation. But it will only be correct if you know that first entry is t = 0

Comment: Infact the other approach I mentioned won't be exactly correct. It will give the phase differnce when the phase of wave 1 is zero not when time is zero. You should try the other way.

Comment: OK, then actual the first possibility is the best. Maybe it would be possible to fit the 150 kHz, switch the frequency of the function and make a calculation with the new function? Or would i lose the phase information with it?

Comment: The first is not actually the correct way. You should only look at times which are multiples of time periods of 50khz wave. Anypoint in between might not be correct. Also the way you said might not be enough since phases of both waves are not the same. Do you have any information oj time data?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it would be possible to get the 50 kHz as rect angular signal.

Comment: See the issue is since both the waves have different frequencies, the phase difference is not constant wrt time. So you can get the phase difference at a particular time. Now you have to decide a reference point where you want the phase difference. One option is when time is multiple of time period. For that you will have to know when is t = 0. Second option is to get the phase difference when Phase of wave 1 is 0. For that you might need interpolation (or a rectangular wave can give it directly). You have to make a choice now. This choice will largely depend on what you use the phase differen

Comment: This choice will depend on what you use the phase difference for.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it. The datas are coming in blocks as i attached in the post (results1 (50kHz), results2 (150kHz)) I am looking for the phase shift in real time.